# SQL constant value or date function performance

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, datetime

Would there be any performance difference between these two queries on SQL Server 2008?

```
SUM(CASE WHEN Date > DATEADD(M, -3, GETDATE()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Active
```

and

```
SUM(CASE WHEN Date > '2013-11-28' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Acttive
```

Or is there a better implementation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for your question for a better implementation:
Your queries literally simulate the `COUNT` function.

```
SELECT COUNT(Date)
FROM tblX
WHERE Date > DATEADD(M, -3, GETDATE())
```

Btw., in TSQL you should write date literals as `'20131128'`.

The question for the 'difference' does not make any sense to me. I guess you figure that it will yield different results tomorrow...

**EDIT**:

The performance of both queries should be the same. There is only an impact if you use a function on the Column value itself, `GETDATE()` does not get executed for every line in your example (I assume, not tested).
See here:  [SARGability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) - examples 1 and 4 especially.

Comment: Thanks for that. By "difference" I meant any performance difference, as I thought that the function would be executed as many times as number of records in the table.

Comment: It's clear _Sargablility_ is an important issue to consider when writing SQL (and you made a good point with it), but I think that's not the case here, it's comparing performance from a constant value against a deterministic function over a constant value, that, for SQL Server, is the same.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that one is hardcoded to 28 Nov 2013, the other is 3 months ago.
So tomorrow one will give different values...

You could parametrise the literal of course, so it could be 4 months or 2 months etc, but you still need a calculation to work out the cutoff dates.

Otherwise, there is no almost no difference in efficiency: the rest of the query (JOIN, WHERE etc) determines query performance because this SUM will be performed quite late

Comment: Thanks. That what I meant to calculate the literal first and save it to a variable instead using date function in `CASE` if there was any performance gain.

Answer (score 0):

The functions over scalar values are calculated once and reused through the query, thus, there's no difference from both queries in performance perspective.